# PySpark: Update column values for a given number of rows of a DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a `DataFrame` with 10 rows and 2 columns: an `ID` column with random identifier values and a `VAL` column filled with `None`.

```
vals = [
        Row(ID=1,VAL=None),
        Row(ID=2,VAL=None),
        Row(ID=3,VAL=None),
        Row(ID=4,VAL=None),
        Row(ID=5,VAL=None),
        Row(ID=6,VAL=None),
        Row(ID=7,VAL=None),
        Row(ID=8,VAL=None),
        Row(ID=9,VAL=None),
        Row(ID=10,VAL=None)
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(vals)
```

Now lets say I want to update the `VAL` column for 3 Rows with value "*lets*", 3 Rows with value "*bucket*" and 4 Rows with value "*this*".

Is there a straightforward way of doing this in PySpark?

Note: ID values is not necessarily consecutive, bucket distribution is not necessarily even

Comment: Yes- what is the criteria for selecting which rows get which new value?

Comment: User defined criteria not based in values of other columns. The whole dataset is treated as equals.

Comment: You'll have to either accept approximation, or solution which won't scale well in general case. A lot depends on the number of unique labels and the amount of data.

Comment: Is there a any criteria for updating?

Comment: @user8371915 unique labels will not be many, but row number is in the order of 100s of millions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to explain an idea with some pseudo-code and you'll map to your solution.

Using window function on one partition we can generate `row_number()` sequential number for each row in dataframe and store it let say in column `row_num`.
Next your "rules" can be represented as another little dataframe: `[min_row_num, max_row_num, label]`.

All you need is to join those two datasets on row number, adding new column:

```
df1.join(df2, 
   on=col('df1.row_num').between(col('min_row_num'), col('max_row_num'))
  )
.select('df1.*', 'df2.label')
```